Hybrid neural network | Images (image data generator) + tabular data
Problem: I am using Python and Keras. I am trying to build a Neural Network (NN) that accepts both images and tabular data as inputs. Classification problem (label has 4 options). I want to pass the images using "ImageDataGenerator" (to use data augmentation) and "flow_from_dataframe". Below you can see some basic code where:
1. Clean tabular data and build the NN.

train_df_tabular_x = train_df[['age', 'sex',]]
val_df_tabular_x = val_df[['age', 'sex']]
test_df_tabular_x = test_df[['age', 'sex']]

train_df_tabular_y = train_df['label']
val_df_tabular_y = val_df['label']
test_df_tabular_y = test_df['label']

encoder = LabelEncoder()
train_df_tabular_y_encoded = encoder.fit_transform(train_df_tabular_y)
train_df_tabular_y_encoded = to_categorical(train_df_tabular_y_encoded)

val_df_tabular_y_encoded = encoder.fit_transform(val_df_tabular_y)
val_df_tabular_y_encoded = to_categorical(val_df_tabular_y_encoded)

test_df_tabular_y_encoded = encoder.fit_transform(test_df_tabular_y)
test_df_tabular_y_encoded = to_categorical(test_df_tabular_y_encoded)

tabular_input = Input(shape = (train_df_tabular_x.shape[1], ), name = 'tabular_features_input')
x = Dense(train_df_tabular_x.shape[1], activation = 'relu', name = 'A')(tabular_input)
x = Dense(16, activation = 'relu', name = 'B')(x)
dense_hidden = Dense(8, activation = 'relu', name = 'C')(x)
last_layer = Dense(4, activation = 'relu', name = 'D')(dense_hidden)
model_tabular = Model(inputs=tabular_input, outputs=last_layer)
print(model_tabular.summary())
plot_model(model_tabular, show_layer_activations=True, show_layer_names=True,show_trainable=True, show_shapes=True)


2. Initialized the data loaders and build a CNN (transfer learning from VGG16).
image_train_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1/255.0,
    rotation_range = 10,
    brightness_range = (0.8, 1.2)
        )
image_val_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1/255.0)
image_test_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1/255.0)


image_train_generator = image_train_generator.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe = train_df,
        x_col = "cxr_path",  # this is where your image data is stored
        y_col = "label",  # this is your target feature
        class_mode = "categorical",  # use "raw" for regressions
        color_mode = 'rgb',
        target_size = (img_size.size[0], img_size.size[1]),
        batch_size = 32, # increase or decrease to fit your GPU,
        )

image_val_generator = image_val_generator.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe = val_df,
        x_col = "cxr_path",  # this is where your image data is stored
        y_col = "label",  # this is your target feature
        class_mode = "categorical",  # use "raw" for regressions
        color_mode = 'rgb',
        target_size = (img_size.size[0], img_size.size[1]),
        batch_size = 32, # increase or decrease to fit your GPU,
        )

image_test_generator = image_test_generator.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe = test_df,
        x_col = "cxr_path",  # this is where your image data is stored
        y_col = "label",  # this is your target feature
        class_mode = "categorical",  # use "raw" for regressions
        color_mode = 'rgb',
        target_size = (img_size.size[0], img_size.size[1]),
        batch_size = 32, # increase or decrease to fit your GPU,
        )

model_img = vgg16.VGG16(input_tensor = Input(shape = (image_train_generator.image_shape[0], image_train_generator.image_shape[1], 3)),
                        # input_shape = (image_train_generator.image_shape[0], image_train_generator.image_shape[1], 3), 
                        include_top = False,
                        pooling = 'avg',
                        weights = 'imagenet')
model_img.trainable = False

img_input = Input(shape = (image_train_generator.image_shape[0], image_train_generator.image_shape[1], 3), name = 'img_features_input')
x = model_img(img_input, training = False)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
x = Dense(512, activation = 'relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
x = Dense(256, activation = 'relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
last_layer = Dense(32, activation = 'relu')(x)
model_img = Model(inputs = img_input, outputs = last_layer)
print(model_img.summary())

3. Concatenated the two networks (images and tabular) and compiled.
x = concatenate([model_tabular.output, model_img.output])
x = Dense(36, activation="relu", name = 'dense_hidden_final_1')(x)
x = Dense(16, activation="relu", name = 'dense_hidden_final_2')(x)
x = Dense(8, activation="relu", name = 'dense_hidden_final_3')(x)
last_layer = Dense(4, activation = 'softmax', name = 'super_output')(x)

model = Model(inputs = [model_img.input, model_tabular.input], # [0] because, for some reason, the inputs were originally as lists???
              outputs = [last_layer])

model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer = AdamW(),
              metrics = ['accuracy'])

lr_schedule = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor = 'val_loss', factor = 0.1, patience = 1, min_lr = 0.00001, cooldown = 1)
stop = EarlyStopping(monitor = "val_loss", patience = 5, mode = 'min')
best = ModelCheckpoint(filepath = './best_model.keras', save_best_only = True, monitor = 'val_loss', mode = 'min', verbose = 0)

4. Defined a function that, I thought, would help pass both the images and the tabular data, while using the data loaders for the images.
def tabular_generator(dataframe, image_gen):
    while True:
        # Get next batch from the image generator
        batch_x, batch_y = next(image_gen)
        # Fetch indices of the current batch
        batch_indices = image_gen.index_array
        # Retrieve corresponding tabular data using these indices
        batch_tabular = dataframe.iloc[batch_indices].drop(['cxr_path', 'label'], axis = 1).values
        yield [batch_x, batch_tabular], batch_y

combined_generator_train = tabular_generator(train_df[['age', 'sex', 'cxr_path', 'label']], image_train_generator)
combined_generator_val = tabular_generator(val_df[['age', 'sex', 'cxr_path', 'label']], image_val_generator)

5. Trained the concatenated model using my last function to pass the data
results_img = model.fit(
    combined_generator_train,
    epochs = 50,
    callbacks = [lr_schedule, stop, best],
    validation_data = combined_generator_val
)

Error I get:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[114], line 1
----> 1 results_img = model.fit(
      2      combined_generator_train,
      3     epochs = 50,
      4     callbacks = [lr_schedule, stop, best],
      5     validation_data = combined_generator_val
      6 )

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py:123, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    120     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
    121     # To get the full stack trace, call:
    122     # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 123     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    124 finally:
    125     del filtered_tb

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/from_generator_op.py:124, in _from_generator(generator, output_types, output_shapes, args, output_signature, name)
    122   for spec in nest.flatten(output_signature):
    123     if not isinstance(spec, type_spec.TypeSpec):
--> 124       raise TypeError(f"`output_signature` must contain objects that are "
    125                       f"subclass of `tf.TypeSpec` but found {type(spec)} "
    126                       f"which is not.")
    127 else:
    128   if output_types is None:

TypeError: `output_signature` must contain objects that are subclass of `tf.TypeSpec` but found <class 'list'> which is not.

I tried to fix it with:
output_signature = (
    (tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32),  # For image data
     tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, 2), dtype=tf.float32)),           # For tabular data (only had two columns)
    tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, 4), dtype=tf.int32)                # For labels (outcome has 4 levels)
)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    lambda: tabular_generator(train_df[['age', 'sex', 'cxr_path', 'label']], image_train_generator),
    output_signature=output_signature
)

dataset2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    lambda: tabular_generator(val_df[['age', 'sex', 'cxr_path', 'label']], image_val_generator),
    output_signature=output_signature
)

results_img = model.fit(
     dataset,
    epochs = 50,
    callbacks = [lr_schedule, stop, best],
    validation_data = dataset2
)

But got another error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[36], line 1
----> 1 results_img = model.fit(
      2      dataset,
      3     epochs = 50,
      4     callbacks = [lr_schedule, stop, best],
      5     validation_data = dataset2
      6 )

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py:123, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    120     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
    121     # To get the full stack trace, call:
    122     # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 123     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    124 finally:
    125     del filtered_tb

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py:53, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     51 try:
     52   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 53   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     54                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     55 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     56   if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node PyFunc defined at (most recent call last):
<stack traces unavailable>
TypeError: `generator` yielded an element that did not match the expected structure. The expected structure was ((tf.float32, tf.float32), tf.int32), but the yielded element was ([array([[[[0.03137255, 0.03137255, 0.03137255],....

I just ran out of ideas. Any help will be greatly appreciated!
